# Flex in C produces Unsupported 16 bit Application while compiling on 64 bit Windows 7 Machine

Tags: c++, c, windows, flex-lexer, lex

I am using 64 bit Windows 7 OS. I have installed 32 bit Flex and Bison from Sourceforge as per the following instructions:
http://www.surajgaikwad.com/2013/10/compile-lex-and-yacc-progs-on-windows.html

The only difference is I am not using dev-cpp but I am using mingw cpp as dev-cpp was giving me an error.

Now, I have written a lexical analyzer and I execute the following:

a) When I compile it using flex using the following command, it compiles successfully:
flex test.l

b) When I compile the lex.yy.c file produced  by step (a), using the following command, it executes OK as well:
cpp lex.yy.c

c) However, when I try to send this output to an executable file using the command:
cpp lex.yy.c -o a.exe

This a.exe does not run and gives me an error which says:
"This version of E:...\src\a.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher."

The header of the pop-up says "Unsupported 16-Bit Application"

I was under the impression that 64 bit windows should be able to execute any 32 bit or 16 bit application. Moreover, I am puzzled, why the compiler is generating 16-bit application.

May I request you to please share your opinion of the probable causes of this issue or any same/similar experiences so that I can investigate further to find the root cause.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What compiler is "cpp"? The link says to use `gcc`?

Comment: @MatsPetersson - Its cpp compiler. gcc does not compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was under the impression that 64 bit windows should be able to execute any 32 bit or 16 bit application.

That's a misapprehension on your part. As per [KB896458](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/896458):

> 64-bit versions of Windows do not support 16-bit components, 16-bit processes, or 16-bit applications.

Your `cpp` compiler is obviously producing a 16-bit application, which 64-bit Windows will not run.

I'm not entirely sure what compiler you're actually using, since the instructions you link to seem to require `gcc` for the compilation part, rather than `cpp`.

It *may* be worthwhile trying to figure out what model and version compiler you're using, such as with `cpp --help`, `cpp -h` or `cpp -?`. That will make it easier to track down *why* you're getting a 16-bit executable.

Answer (score -1):

Remove "-c" from gcc parameters. For me worked :D